# Use __($str) and _e($str) to translate strings with HTML

Tags: theme-development, localization

I'm currently developing a non-trivial theme right now, most of the time I'm not using [a `__($str)` translate function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) when there's an HTML tag therein the text. Is it good to always use the translate functions such `__($str)` and `_e($str)` whenever there's a text that'll be going to output? Any downside with it?

Can I still use it even to a very long text that have mixed with an HTML tag such like this?

```
__("This <em>text</em> have an <b>HTML</b> tag. Another sentence...")
```

Or it is good to use like this? *(*Looks messy..)*

```
__('This ').'<em>'.__('text').'</em>'.' have an '.'<b>'.__('HTML').'</b>'__(' tag.')
```

How to properly use such kind of a function?

Comment: it depends of the sentence. to choose you have to think if it's clear for the translator. in the 2nd case, he will have to translate " have an" and "This " then in this case it would be clearer to translate the whole sentence in one time.   when a sentence is to complicated, you can also use `sprintf` to cut the sentence

Comment: @mmm So you mean translating the whole paragraph that had `innerHTML` tags works well? Could you provide me a link to an article that proves your saying?

Comment: A good information source is the WordPress codex article »[I18n for WordPress Developers](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)«.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sweet and short of it all is, never try to translate HTML tags. Use placeholders and either `printf` or `sprintf` to translate strings with HTML tags

Something like this will do

### [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf( __( 'This %s text %s have an %s HTML %s tag. Another sentence...' ), '<em>', '</em>', '<b>', '</b>' );
```

### [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf( __( 'This %s text %s have an %s HTML %s tag. Another sentence...' ), '<em>', '</em>', '<b>', '</b>' );
```

Comment: @ialocin Thanks for the edit, noddy badge for me for forgetting those brackets :-)

Comment: It happens and this is after all a community effort :)

Answer (score 3):

The second option will not only (as @mmm already said) confuse translators, but also the order of words in a sentence can be significantly different from one language to another.

With the first option a translator can adjust and translate properly, which is not possible with the second one.